# Not able to copy and pass the link below on my Ipad for the "are you a robot test".

Tags: support, bug, captcha

I just noticed I can't ask question on the math forum because of the "are you a robot" test which ask to copy and paste a link that I can't paste in the tiny box.
My brother encountered the same problem on his own ipad.

How can this be fixed without impeding this site to protect itself from robots?

Comment: Gain more reputation so the site reduces CAPTCHA checks to a minimum... :-P

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the page with this request? I've never seen that kind of captcha here.

Comment: see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21470/im-not-a-robot

Comment: Yes, I will add some pictures in a few hours when I get my Ipad back.